# Custom UUID implementation on C++

Tags: c++, random, c++17

The code's gonna be pretty simple and YES, I do know, what a proper UUID4 implementation is and what are possible approaches to implement RFC 4122.

But somewhere there exists a small piece of software, where possible dependencies should be minified if possible. Because of this and some other reason let's consider the following UUID generator:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <random>

static std::string generate_uuid(size_t len) {
  static const char x[] = "0123456789abcdef";

  std::string uuid;
  uuid.reserve(len);

  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 gen(rd());

  std::uniform_int_distribution < > dis(0, sizeof(x) - 2);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    uuid += x[dis(gen)];

  return uuid;
}
```

The output of the function is to be used in cases when some unique ID is required for a custom storage. Like "here we put this data, and there is its 16-byte ID", meaning it would be enough if collisions are just "not likely at all, like winning a lottery twice in a row".

As far as modern C++ has improved random utils, it seemed a not-so-bad custom solution, but now I'm not that sure.

What would you say? Thanks in advance

Comment: UUID is just a 16 byte number. Why not simply compose two 64bit random numbers? Why do you treat it as a string? Also I heard somewhere that some of it's indexes have special meaning - like who generated it or something.

Comment: Note that the below answers are good if you just want to learn C++. You should never use such a uuid in a real production system, because the random number generator is not creating unique numbers. Random is not the same as unique or even likely unique.

Comment: NoNoNoNo. When people print out UUID they print out the hex version because otherwise it is not "very" human-readable. You should treat them as numbers internally just have a mechanism for printing them in hex (like overload the operator<< for your UUID type). Building a random number generator every time can be very expensive (at least make those static members of the function). Why not have a time component. Much more likely you are not going to clash (assuming time portion is large). then have the random part as the differentiator from UUID generated on the same second/millisecond.

Comment: All those considerations about the code quality are definitely true, it IS a rather simplified version and the random generator constructor is not a performance issue in my case even slightly. But what I really badly need to know is -- can I rely on the randomness of the resulting string? An important question is -- if I would need those IDs to be an unique key in my storage, would this version be sufficient? I HAVE mentioned that have seen the RFC for uuid, but not in strict theory -- will my code work in practice?

Comment: I'd say that as long as you're using `std::mt19937` which isn't a cryptographically secure random number generator, this is a failed attempt. You should not be able to predict next ID's given any set of IDs. You say that you know what a UUID is, but for some reason you don't format it as one, without indication **why**. If the length is too small then it may not be as unique as you might expect. The length is also specified in hex instead of binary, which is confusing to say the least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to include `<string>`, and misspelt `std::size_t` (twice).

Since this doesn't create a RFC-4122-compliant UUID, I would change the name so it doesn't get used where it shouldn't.  Perhaps `create_random_id()` or similar?

I don't like the name `x` for the digit string - I'd prefer something more descriptive like `hex_chars` or even just `hex`.

---

We could consider constructing a string that's already long enough, then setting all its characters:

```
std::string uuid(len, '\0');
for (auto& c: uuid) {
    c = x[dis(gen)];
}
```

Or perhaps replace the loop with a standard algorithm:

```
std::string uuid;
uuid.reserve(len);
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(uuid), len,
                [&]{ return x[dis(gen)]; });
```

Though I don't think that's necessarily clearer.

---

Going a little over the top, we could make a general select-from-collection function and use that:

```
template<std::ranges::sized_range C, class G>
auto sample_from(C const& collection, G&& generator)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<typename C::size_type> dis{0, std::ranges::size(collection) - 1};
    return collection[dis(generator)];
}
```

⋮

```
    static const std::string_view hex_chars = "0123456789abcdef";
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(uuid), len,
                    [&]{ return sample_from(hex_chars, gen); });
```

---

We might even make a custom input-iterator for selecting random characters:

```
class random_char_source
{
    const std::string chars;
    std::mt19937 generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> distribution;

public:
    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = char;
    using difference_type = int;
    using pointer = const char*;
    using reference = const char&;

    explicit random_char_source(std::string chars, std::random_device::result_type seed = std::random_device{}())
        : chars{std::move(chars)},
          generator{seed},
          distribution{0, this->chars.size() - 1}
    {}

    // it's an input iterator
    char operator*() { return chars[distribution(generator)]; }
    random_char_source& operator++() { return *this; }
};
```

That makes our ID generator very simple:

```
static std::string generate_random_id(std::size_t len)
{
    auto hex_chars = random_char_source{"0123456789abcdef"};

    std::string uuid;
    uuid.reserve(len);
    std::copy_n(hex_chars, len, std::back_inserter(uuid));
    return uuid;
}
```

---

However, for generating power-of-two numbers, and since we have a UniformRandomBitGenerator (the `std::mt19937` object), we can extract bits directly:

```
static std::string random_id(std::size_t len)
{
    static const std::string_view hex_chars = "0123456789abcdef";
    using Generator = std::mt19937;

    Generator gen{std::random_device{}()};

    std::string uuid;
    uuid.reserve(len);

    while (uuid.size() < len) {
        auto n = gen();
        for (auto i = Generator::max();  i & 0x8 && uuid.size() < len;  i >>= 4) {
            uuid += hex_chars[n & 0xf];
            n >>= 4;
        }
    }

    return uuid;
}
```

You could probably make a simpler and more readable version of that.

Comment: You should make the generator static. I believe it is expensive to initialize. Once initialized can be reused indefinitely.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Could I clarify just one thing -- would any of the following be enough to rely on it as something random enough to most likely not have collisions? (uniqueness on large scales is gonna be somewhat important) Seems like "yes", just wanted to be sure

Comment: I don't think there's anything to reduce the randomness, so the average number of ids generated before the first collision will be 2 ^ (len/2).  You can obviously tune the length for the amount of collision-resistance you need.

Answer (score 4):

I agree it's odd to generate random hex digits directly, rather than just formatting a few large ints as hex.  Unlike Toby's code though, I think it would be simpler to use library code to format the random integers into hex.  If you append too many digits, just truncate the string.  [to_chars](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars) in C++17 is *very efficient* but a little harder to use.

But in this code:

`static const char x[] = "0123456789abcdef";`
Use `constexpr`.

`sizeof(x)`
Don't use `sizeof` on arrays to get the element count.  This is easy to get wrong and if the definition of `x` changes then it will silently do the wrong thing.  `std::size(x)` works here, as do a number of other standard library mechanisms.

Do you only need one random ID, or one every once in a long while?  OK.  But if you're calling this repeatedly, you're doing the expensive overhead of initializing the random number generator to a "true" random number, each time.  It would be better to make a factory class that holds the random number generator, initialized in the constructor.

Comment: `std::to_chars()` is quite awkward because you need to insert any leading zeros yourself.  There's a possible case for `std::sprintf()` here, though you'll need to work out how many digits are usable.

Comment: Thanks! Just a side note -- compared with the rest of the code, that constructor costs almost nothing in the case, though making it static or something is a good idea, yes.

Comment: @TobySpeight If you append the full result of `sprintf`, drop out of the loop if the string is now long enough, and finally truncate the string if it's too long.